# How to add source files generated in target folder as library in Intellij Idea

Tags: web-services, maven, intellij-idea, proxy-classes

I'm trying to checkout a maven project from SubVersion. In the pom.xml file it's specified to generate web service proxy classes in the target folder. Here's the concerned part of the pom.xml file:

```
          <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>

                    <wsdlUrls>                               
                        <wsdlUrl>${basedir}/config/mnpBusinessService.wsdl</wsdlUrl>
                    </wsdlUrls>

                    <packageName>com.mnp.services.business</packageName>
                    <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/target/generated-code/src</sourceDestDir>
                </configuration>
                <id>ws-import-mnpBusinessService</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
           </execution>
```

As you can see the maven is instructed to create the generated proxy classes in the `${basedir}/target/generated-code/src` directory. When I checkout with NetBeans, a seperate GeneratedCode directory is created as part of the project. And any package inside this directory is available to the main source files. But when I checkout with Intellij Idea,

1. I have to manually execute install command and second.
2. The files are indeed created in the specified directory but main source files can't see those packages.

I've tried Project Structure|Modules|MyModule|Dependencies|Add Jars or directories and Project Structure|Libraries|Add|Java|Mydiectoryy. But neither helped. I also tried removing the `target` folder from Exclude list but that didn't help either. What should I do to be able to import generated proxy classes in Intellij Idea. It's the Ultimate version 2016.2.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up creating a module from existing sources, where existing sources folder is my `generated-code` folder. Then from the Modules|My main module|Dependencies|Add module and chose the just created module. And voila.

Here are the steps I followed:

**1.**

[image]

**2.**

[image]

**3**

[image]

**4**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**2022 UPDATE**

In my case, I was manually running an ant build script to generate required source files before attempting to compile the main sources. The maven `generatedSourcesDirectory` seems primarily meant for annotations, but it provides an automated one-line solution to this problem.

Change `${basedir}/target/generated-code/src` to `${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java` and add this line to the maven-compiler-plugin `<configuration>` section:

```
<generatedSourcesDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/main/java</generatedSourcesDirectory>
```

You may need `Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven` enabled. It's in Build Tools | Maven | Runner.